# How can I render Google Translate Widget only once using useEffect Hook in Next JS Project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, google-translate

```
    import { useEffect } from "react";

    const GoogleTranslate = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
    let addScript = document.createElement("script");
    addScript.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"
    );

    document.body.appendChild(addScript);

    window.googleTranslateElementInit = googleTranslateElementInit;
    }, []);

    const googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
    return new window.google.translate.TranslateElement(
      {
        pageLanguage: "en",
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.BUTTON,
      },
      "google_translate_element"
      );
     };
    return <div id="google_translate_element"></div>;
   };

   export default GoogleTranslate;
```

Here is my Component. I have used in a single page. But instead of once I am getting two separate instance of google translate button.

So, I want to know how to render only once this button.

Here is the UI image

[Double Google translate button bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L7f7.png)

Comment: Look at your parent component. Where is it using your `GoogleTranslate` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` may run twice despite an empty dependency array in multiple circumstances (for example, if a parent component is re-rendering, or if you have React StrictMode enabled).

Hence, you are probably creating 2 elements inside `useEffect`.

You could analyze your code and check for potential unwanted re-renders or simply replace `useEffect` with this `useEffectOnce` hook:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const useEffectOnce = (effect: () => void | (() => void)) => {
  const effectFn = useRef<() => void | (() => void)>(effect);
  const destroyFn = useRef<void | (() => void)>();
  const effectCalled = useRef(false);
  const rendered = useRef(false);
  const [, setVal] = useState<number>(0);

  if (effectCalled.current) {
    rendered.current = true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!effectCalled.current) {
      destroyFn.current = effectFn.current();
      effectCalled.current = true;
    }

    setVal(val => val + 1);

    return () => {
      if (!rendered.current) {
        return;
      }

      if (destroyFn.current) {
        destroyFn.current();
      }
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Just create a file with this code, and import and use it instead of `useEffect`.

Comment: I Understood. Thank You. Again this problem is not happening in build env but in dev env. What would be the reason? I have faced similar kind of issue while tried to make custom navigation buttons for Swiper Slider. In that case, in dev env, no problem but in build env buttons were not wroking as expected?  So, why is this happening that sometimes dev env working well but not build and sometimes build but not dev? Would you like to explain a bit?

Comment: @MusiurAlamOpu It pretty much only happens in dev and not in prod if you React StrictMode enabled (often enabled by default if you use create-react-app or next.js for example). In that case, all components will render twice (only in dev-mode), which shouldn't be a problem if your useEffect hook only performs side-effects that need no cleanup (e.g. calling an API which can be performed twice without any visual bugs). In your case, your component modifies the global body of the page, which is "outside of its scope" and either requires manual cleanup or requires you to only call useEffect once.

Comment: If you have some bugs in production but not in dev it will most likely not be caused by this issue but something else.

Comment: Again, Thank you. You have answered half of my question. Now I have to search for other part. : )